# Custom Text tabs width/height

Tags: docusignapi

I am using Docusign REST API to place custom text tabs in the document. But the tabs are getting placed with a default width and height. Is there a way to control the width and height?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the `width` and `height` parameters will allow you to resize a text tab.

If you want to change the size of a SignHere or Initial tab, `scaleValue` can be used instead.